# Use reflection to get all public properties in poco class not including enum property

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-6.0

I'm using reflection to retrieve all of the public properties of a poco class

poco e.g.

```cs
 public class MetaData
    {
        [ExplicitKey]
        public string Id{ get; set; }

        
        public enum DataType
        {
            T1 = 1,
            T2 = 2,
            T3 = 3
        }
        
        public DataType MyDataType { get; private set; } //<- enum
        
        public string ParentFolder { get; private set; }

        public string FileName { get; private set; }
...
```

Using reflection to obtain all of those properties seems to always exclude the enum property:
e.q.

```cs
var publicPropertiesUsed = metaData.GetType().GetProperties().Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsPublic);
```

When interrogating the enum property, `IsPublic` is false.

What's the correct way to obtain all the public properties through reflection?

Comment: Could you not use the property name?  Then specify certain aspect for the enum?

Comment: Your code does not even compile - you can't have a property with the same name as a nested type.

Comment: @DStanley Typo. Example Code fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataType` `enum` is nested within your `MetaData` class.
In such case `IsPublic` returns `false`.

From the `IsPublic` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.ispublic)

> `true` if the `Type` is declared public and **is not a nested type**; otherwise, `false`.

Either move that `enum` outside that `MetaData` class
or use [`IsVisible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvisible) instead of `IsPublic`.

From the `IsVisble` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isvisible)

> `true` if the current `Type` is a public type or **a public nested type** such that all the enclosing types are public; otherwise, `false`.

```
var publicPropertiesUsed = 
    metaData.GetType()
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(x => x.PropertyType.IsVisble);
```

Comment: Thanks. This answers it. ... `IsVisible` and `IsPublic` use are counterintuitive to me.